# Install Error: 'rubygems' has no installation candidate

Tags: rubygems

Hi I would appreciate some help installing rubygems. This is what happens when I try. "ruby-full" has already been installed. How do I fix this? What is the issue?

```
$ sudo apt-get install rubygems 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package rubygems is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  ruby

E: Package 'rubygems' has no installation candidate
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04. Ruby version installed: 1:1.9.3.4. Please let me know if there are any other additional details that could help solve this issue.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

In **Ubuntu 14.04**, try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems-integration
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked like a charm. It seems that there is something in the 'standard' ruby package that I installed that was preventing me from installing rubygems?

Comment: Older rubygems:

Description-en: package management framework for Ruby libraries/applications
 This is a way to package Ruby libraries/applications for distribution.
 RubyGems provides the ability to manage concurrent versions of libraries and
 dependencies between those libraries. Using RubyGems, you can:
   * download and install Ruby libraries easily
   * not worry about libraries A and B depending on different versions of
     library C
   * easily remove libraries you no longer use
 .
 This package provides Rubygems for Ruby 1.8. In Ruby 1.9.X, Rubygems is
 provided with the interpreter.

Comment: So it appears that rubygems is no longer a separate package in newer versions of Ruby?